# second router dhcp problems

Tags: router, dhcp

here is the situation:
bevor

asus router rt-n66u (192.168.1.1) for my appartment --> netgear wifi-repeater for my sisters appartment 50 meters away (free line of sight), the ip adresses for all devices on the repeater had the ip 192.168.1.x
i could see them in my router, and access her raspberry pi.

because the connection was crappy i upgraded the netgear repeater to 2 Ubiquiti nanostations m2 loco + linksys ea3500

situation now:

my asus rt-n66u via ethernet to nanostation (accesspoint) --> nanostation (Station) via ethernet --> linksys ea3500

everything works great, but strangely my linksys ip is now 10.3.2.x 
i only can connect to the router when im on her wifi.

i read somewhere that when 2 routers are in use that only 1 dhcp server should be active

i disabled dhcp on linksys, but than i could not reconnect to the linksys router and internet, so i had to reset.

is there something else i have to to when disable the dhcp, so i can reconnect.

this is my linksys setup now (with dhcp)
https://i.imgsafe.org/1168741f89.png ,
https://i.imgsafe.org/11687d06e0.png ,
https://i.imgsafe.org/116883596e.png ,

hope someone can help me understand

Answer (score 0):

i had to set the linksys to bridge mode, this disables the dhcp automatically.